# Making JQuery Drop Down Code Re-usable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I've found a drop down on Codrops that I'd like to use in my application - it's example #5 on this page: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/10/04/custom-drop-down-list-styling/

I've popped it onto my page with the CSS and and the JS and it works  and looks good etc, but when I've started to add another one and realized that it's not going to work because the code is engineered to only work for one drop down and to make it work for multiple I'd have to duplicate the JS code which I'm not keen to do and standards wise it's not the right way of doing it.

I'me just not sure how I can create something that will pass in the dropdowns and set click events for each of them as in production most of these boxes are going to come onto the page dynamically.

I've created a fiddle of the dropdown and the code I'm using here: https://jsfiddle.net/WebDevelopWolf/jou30bvg/

And the JS part of the code is (this is in the fiddle too):

```
function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
        var obj = this;

        obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            event.stopPropagation();
        }); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );
    $(document).click(function() {
        // all dropdowns
        $('.wrapper-dropdown-5').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: In html an ID is uniq, then if you use an ID to generate your DropDown only the first element is used. Then use a class to identify all the dropdown or create different dropdown with different ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I did was to cut a bit from your code and it can be reused.

```
function DropDown(el) {
    el.on('click', function(event){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      event.stopPropagation();
    }); 
}


new DropDown( $('#dd') );
```

here Is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/jou30bvg/3/